# Select only one checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a multiple checkboxes, but I want user to select one checkbox only. I try if-else statement but it is not useable. So, I want to know, how to be like that.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons?

Comment: Please, try to use combobox. That lets you to select only one option.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why don't you use Radio Buttons instead? They are meant exactly for that.

But if you insist on using check boxes, modify the event of on select of any check box such that when it is selected it disables the other check boxes.

Comment: Is it not the same? So, I still need to disable Radio Button right? How to do that? thanks ka

Comment: Radio buttons are normally used together in a RadioGroup. When several radio buttons live inside a radio group, checking one radio button unchecks all the others automatically. Have a look at this URL: http://java.dzone.com/articles/google-android-tutorial?page=0,4

Comment: With Radiobuttons, you cannot uncheck by clicking the same button. For example, if you want users to give options to choose A or B or None of those.

Answer (score 3):

I made this:

```
public void check_checkbox(){

    int CB_count=0;
    if (CB_1.isChecked()) {
        CB_count=CB_count+1;
    }if (CB_2.isChecked()) {
        CB_count=CB_count+1;
    }if (CB_3.isChecked()) {
            CB_count=CB_count+1;}

        if (CB_count == 1) {

            //do your magic

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "you only can select 1 checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

I improve it, on the onCreateView=

```
CB_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    CB_2.setChecked(false);
                    CB_3.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
        CB_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    CB_1.setChecked(false);
                    CB_3.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
        CB_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    CB_2.setChecked(false);
                    CB_1.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

it's recommended to use Radio Buttons instead but as in my case I had to follow design so I did it like that using Kotlin.

override `setOnClickListener` when checkBox clicked make other check boxes unchecked

```
driver_check_box.setOnClickListener() {
            driver_check_box.isChecked = true
            station_check_box.isChecked = false
            broadcast_check_box.isChecked = false

        }
        station_check_box.setOnClickListener {
            driver_check_box.isChecked = false
            station_check_box.isChecked = true
            broadcast_check_box.isChecked = false

        }
        broadcast_check_box.setOnClickListener {
            driver_check_box.isChecked = false
            station_check_box.isChecked = false
            broadcast_check_box.isChecked = true
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

**- In my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:background="#ff99f6ff"
  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/escudo"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/dicon2"
        android:contentDescription="foto logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checkedButton="1"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_a"
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxA"
            android:layout_above="@+id/escudo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_b"
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxB"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBoxA"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxA"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBoxA"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_c"
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxC"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBoxB"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBoxB"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBoxB"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private CheckBox checkBoxA, checkBoxB, checkBoxC;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkBoxA = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxA);
        checkBoxB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxB);
        checkBoxC = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxC);
    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()) {

            case R.id.checkBoxA:

                    checkBoxB.setChecked(false);
                    checkBoxC.setChecked(false);

                break;

            case R.id.checkBoxB:

                    checkBoxC.setChecked(false);
                    checkBoxA.setChecked(false);

                break;

            case R.id.checkBoxC:

                    checkBoxA.setChecked(false);
                    checkBoxB.setChecked(false);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin I manage to do this.

Example

First store a value isChecked in your Object

```
data class OptionsDetails(val optionName: String, var isChecked: Boolean = false)
```

Then, if you are using a recyclerview with multiple CheckBoxes, just check the object that you just pressed

```
inner class OptionRemoveViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<OptionsDetails>(itemView) {
        override fun bind(item: OptionsDetails, position: Int) {

            itemView.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
            itemView.item_name.text = item.optionName
            itemView.checkBox.isChecked = item.isChecked

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                itemView.checkBox.isChecked = !itemView.checkBox.isChecked
            }

            itemView.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                itemClickListener.onCheckBoxClickListener(position)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I have an interface that I will use in my view to interact with that checkbox click, then in my view I just put to false the others checkboxes that are not currently selected and just pass true to `isChecked` to the object I have already pressed.

```
  override fun onCheckBoxClickListener(position:Int) {

        for((index,value) in optionList.withIndex()){
            value.isChecked = position == index
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Thats it, this will let you just check one checkbox at the time

Answer (score 0):

use setoncliklistener

```
gdA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gdAB.setChecked(false);
                gdB.setChecked(false);
                gdO.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
        gdB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gdA.setChecked(false);
                gdAB.setChecked(false);
                gdO.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
        gdAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gdA.setChecked(false);
                gdB.setChecked(false);
                gdO.setChecked(false);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach.

STEP 1

```
chkEnglish.setOnClickListener(checkboxListener);
chkFrench.setOnClickListener(checkboxListener);
```

STEP 2

```
View.OnClickListener checkboxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == chkEnglish){
            chkEnglish.setChecked(true);
            chkFrench.setChecked(false);
        } else   if (v == chkFrench){
            chkFrench.setChecked(true);
            chkEnglish.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val checkBoxList = mutableListOf<CheckBox>()
checkBoxList.add(...)

      checkBoxList.forEach {
        it.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            checkBoxList.forEach {
                it.isChecked = false
            }
            it.isChecked = isChecked
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.