# when the item is click in recyclerview pervious item clicked effects should be gone

Tags: android

**RecyclerView_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/overview_frag_txt_color"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_2">

        <com.custom.SquareLayout
            android:id="@+id/squareLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_5"/

        </com.custom.SquareLayout>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/addresslist"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/overview_frag_txt_color"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

I am having three items in my `recyclerview`. When first item is clicked the `checkbox` is checked with i click the second item I want the `checkbox` of 1st item to be unchecked

Answer (score 0):

you should try RadioButtons instead of CheckBoxes.

Check out this post [Select only one checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844190/select-only-one-checkbox)! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on onChecked event store the position of checkbox  checked in dataset in global variable and call notifydatasetchanged and in onbindViewHolder() function

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   holder.checkBox.setChecked(selectedPostion==position);
 }
```

In your viewHolder class

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            selectedPostion = getAdapterPostion();
            notifydatasetChanged()
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: notifdatasetchanged in my activity or else?please can you elaborate