# Select only one checkbox in section recylerview?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am using sectional recyclerview for add to cart screen. and want to select only one checkbox at a time from various items from category. Below is code and screen image. Please give me solution for select only one checkbox at a time from product categories.[image]

Below is json response,

```
{
 "Status":"Success",
 "StatusCode":"200",
 "Message":"data fetch successfully.",
 "Data":{
  "1":{
     "OptionGroupName":"Base",
     "OptionGroupId":"1",
     "OptionCount":2,
     "Options":[
        {
           "OptionGroupId":"1",
           "OptionGroupName":"Base",
           "ProductId":"54",
           "OptionId":"1",
           "OptionName":"Soft",
           "OptionPrice":"25",
           "IsActive":"1"
        },
        {
           "OptionGroupId":"1",
           "OptionGroupName":"Base",
           "ProductId":"54",
           "OptionId":"2",
           "OptionName":"Hard",
           "OptionPrice":"15",
           "IsActive":"1"
        }
     ]
  },
  "2":{
     "OptionGroupName":"Sauce",
     "OptionGroupId":"2",
     "OptionCount":3,
     "Options":[
        {
           "OptionGroupId":"2",
           "OptionGroupName":"Sauce",
           "ProductId":"54",
           "OptionId":"3",
           "OptionName":"Shezwan",
           "OptionPrice":"10",
           "IsActive":"1"
        },
        {
           "OptionGroupId":"2",
           "OptionGroupName":"Sauce",
           "ProductId":"54",
           "OptionId":"4",
           "OptionName":"Chilly",
           "OptionPrice":"20",
           "IsActive":"1"
        },
        {
           "OptionGroupId":"2",
           "OptionGroupName":"Sauce",
           "ProductId":"54",
           "OptionId":"5",
           "OptionName":"Soya",
           "OptionPrice":"29",
           "IsActive":"1"
        }
     ]
  }
  }
  }
```

This is java code;

```
  public class ProductCartAdapter extends SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ProductCart> allData;

    public ProductCartAdapter(List<ProductCart> data) {
        this.allData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionCount() {
        return allData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(int section) {
        return allData.get(section).getItemList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int section) {
        String sectionName = allData.get(section).getName();
        SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder = (SectionViewHolder) holder;
        sectionViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(sectionName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int section, final int relativePosition, final int absolutePosition) {
        final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        itemViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).getOptionName());
        itemViewHolder.tvProductPrice.setText("+ $" + allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).getOptionPrice());

        **// what I have to code here for selecting only one checkbox (not from addons only from base and sauce)**

        itemViewHolder.cbProduct.setTag(section);
        itemViewHolder.cbProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer pos = (Integer) itemViewHolder.cbProduct.getTag();

                if (allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).isSelected()) {
                    allData.get(pos).getItemList().get(relativePosition).setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    allData.get(pos).getItemList().get(relativePosition).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, boolean header) {
        View v = null;
        if (header) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_section_cart, parent, false);
            return new SectionViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_cart_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(v);
        }

    }

    // SectionViewHolder Class for Sections
    public class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView tvProductName;

        public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
        }
    }

    // ItemViewHolder Class for Items in each Section
    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvProductName, tvProductPrice;
        CheckBox cbProduct;

        public ItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            tvProductPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            cbProduct = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProduct);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844207/6701660 Try this it's the right approach

Comment: You can keep the track of the current position of the checked CheckBox and whenever any other CheckBox is checked update the previous value and refreshes the adapter.

Comment: So you want to checked single Checkbox at a single time from category or over all list?

Answer (score 1):

```
      public class ProductCartAdapter extends SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        private List<ProductCart> allData;

        public ProductCartAdapter(List<ProductCart> data) {
            this.allData = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSectionCount() {
            return allData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount(int section) {
            return allData.get(section).getItemList().size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int section) {
            String sectionName = allData.get(section).getName();
            SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder = (SectionViewHolder) holder;
            sectionViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(sectionName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int section, final int relativePosition, final int absolutePosition) {
            final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
            itemViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).getOptionName());
            itemViewHolder.tvProductPrice.setText("+ $" + allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).getOptionPrice());

            **// what I have to code here for selecting only one checkbox (not from addons only from base and sauce)**

            itemViewHolder.cbProduct.setTag(section);
            itemViewHolder.cbProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    resetCategoryWiseData(section);
                    Integer pos = (Integer) itemViewHolder.cbProduct.getTag();

                    if (allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).isSelected()) {
                        allData.get(pos).getItemList().get(relativePosition).setSelected(false);
                    } else {
                        allData.get(pos).getItemList().get(relativePosition).setSelected(true);
                    }
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
                }
            });

    *********************************************************

        //code for checked/unchecked
        if(allData.get(section).getItemList().get(relativePosition).getSelected()){
        itemViewHolder.cbProduct.setChecked(true);
        }else{
        itemViewHolder.cbProduct.setChecked(false);
        }

    **************************************************************
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, boolean header) {
            View v = null;
            if (header) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_section_cart, parent, false);
                return new SectionViewHolder(v);
            } else {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_cart_item, parent, false);
                return new ItemViewHolder(v);
            }

        }

        // SectionViewHolder Class for Sections
        public class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            final TextView tvProductName;

            public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            }
        }

        // ItemViewHolder Class for Items in each Section
        public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            final TextView tvProductName, tvProductPrice;
            CheckBox cbProduct;

            public ItemViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
                tvProductPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
                cbProduct = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProduct);
            }
        }

private void  resetCategoryWiseData(int section){
    for(int i=0;i<allData.get(section).getItemList().size();i++){
         allData.get(section).getItemList().get(i).setSelected(false);
     }
  }

add this line  **notifyItemChanged(pos);** in click listener of checkox.

and add some code that i have already written in above for ( checkbox is checked or not )


if any issue then tell me.Happy Coding.:)
```

Comment: By using this code , i can select any check box. I only want to select only one -one checkbox at a time from categories base and sauce

Comment: you have 2 ways to do it.1)Store previous selected position via public variable in adpter and uncheck that position.2) unchecked previous position using for loop of that category.if you don't understand then tell me, i will give you a code.

Comment: please can you tell me how to uncheck previous position in particular section after selecting another position?

Comment: I have added 1 method..resetCategoryWiseData().please check my edited answer

Comment: I can still select multiple values

Comment: Can you provide me another solution for this?

Comment: this soluttion is working with me.i think you have some mistake in code for rearrage.

Comment: @dipali don't waste time. He need end to end code like child

Comment: @RanjithKumar i know what he wants.i have provided only this solution as he needed.if you have solution then why you don't give him?

Comment: Code is works bt its take both categories not take particular section

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only one item then use RadioGroup instead or recyclerview(inside one).

So that user will know that he/she can select only one item from the list. This will improve user understanding also it will reduce looping again for checking any item has been checked or not.